# Сравнение строк в Perl

Tags: perl

Есть 2 скаляра со строками, которые необходимо сравнить. Почему не работает, понять не могу. Скобок добавил в последней сроке, чтобы точно снять все вопросы по порядку операций.

```
print ($cVal->{Descr}."\n");
print ($TaskData->{DESCR}."\n");
print ((($cVal->{Descr})ne($TaskData->{DESCR}))."\n");
```

Возвращает:

```
FOO
BAR
1

FOO
FOO
1
```

Comment: А распечатайте еще length от этих строк, может в одной из них не печатаемые символы пробелы какие нибудь в конце строки ...

Comment: Лучше даже не `length`, а `use DDP; p $cVal->{Descr}; p $TaskData->{DESCR};`

Comment: А там точно два скаляра?

Comment: там два списка:) а я не уверен, что ne/eq умеют сравнивать списки так, как этого ожидает вопрошающий

Comment: @KoVadim, из чего следует что списки?

Comment: Там скобки вокруг переменных.

Comment: Это не создаёт из них списки, в чём легко можно убедиться.

Comment: length у строк действительно различается, пока не понял почему (данные берутся из одного и того же поля в БД). Сейчас буду искать источник проблемы. Спасибо